# Ajaxplorer big file download / upload error

Tags: file-upload, download, pydio

I'm using ajaxplorer4.0.4, php5.2 apache2 server my php.ini settings are:

```
safe_mode = Off
max_execution_time = 0 ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds(0 for unlimited)
max_input_time = -1 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data(-1 for unlimited)
memory_limit = 1073741824 ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
post_max_size = 1024M   ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
upload_max_filesize = 1024M ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
```

I have even commented the following line in class.fsAccessWrapper.php for downloads to work

```
if(!ini_get("safe_mode")) @set_time_limit(60);
```

But still getting an error While uploading a big file like 200mb file saying:
"There has been an IO Error:Error #2038"
Where as the jump loader seems to be a good option but after an incomplete upload it shows "FILE ACCESS ERROR" and the AjaXplorer shows "SECURITY TOKEN HAS EXPIRED" my preference is to use html or at least flash uploader, BUT RIGHT NOW iM DESPIRATE TO MAKE ANYTHING WORK... PLEASE HELP.

Im getting incomplete downloads like 40mb out of 150mb or 200mb.

Please help me for what I've been missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jumploader in plugins>uploader>Jumploader

Java-based uploader : not active by default, as Jumploader is not distributed with the application, Java applet to perform huge files uploads with progress, chunks files, and more. See http://jumploader.com/ and see below for installation instructions.

Drop the jumploader_z.jar inside the ajaxplorer plugins/uploader.jumploader/ folder
activate the plugin through the GUI (Settings > Global Configurations > Plugins > Uploader) by disabling the two other uploader plugins, and activating this one.
Go back to a file system repository, and clicking upload should open the Java applet!

also check your apache upload limit